# How come Find method of DbSet does not go to database for value inserted during Seeding method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, entity-framework-6.1

I have a simple Seed method:

```
    protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
    {
        var person = new Person() {Name = "SeededPerson", BirthDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)};
        context.Persons.Add(person);
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

This has been run few times ago but since then I have set the Database Initializer to Null os it is not anymore used.

```
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null); //Nothing is done
```

The project is a Console application and has only this line of code:

```
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            var person = context.Persons.Find(1);
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }
```

The SQL profiler does not return anything.

But, if I am using SingleOrDefault, I do see in the SQL profiler the SELECT.

I know that the Find method goes into the local memory first but since the Seed method is not called and that the context is created for only two lines of code, it should not be in the memory.

How come I do not see in the SQL profiler the query with the Find method?

Comment: Did you check that `Seed` is really **not** called and that `SetInitializer` **is** called by setting breakpoints on those lines (`SetInitializer` and first line in `Seed`)?

Comment: The profiler does not show anything query that provide from the Seed. Also, even if it would have been the case, the context is different since I am create a new one from the console application for the Find operation.